# OpenSource Tool Integration with Website

Tags: security, open-source, integration

I am new to development of web application. I need to use a open source tool (http://subgraph.com/products.html) in my website. This application works as a tool. I need to download it and work as of now. My project is to integrate this with my website and produce results as the same way the tool is working when downloading.

### Questions

How to integrate it with my website and produce the same results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't integrate it. You can't run it in command line to control it and you can't save results to file. Look for other open source tools - i.e [Arachni](http://www.arachni-scanner.com/), [W3AF](http://w3af.org/) or maybe one of the list ([Web Application Security Scaner List](http://projects.webappsec.org/w/page/13246988/Web%20Application%20Security%20Scanner%20List)) can be integrated to webpage.